# PHP mysqli only one user displayed

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops, mysqli

I want to achieve this

> - john -> sub user
> - john -> sub user
> - mark -> sub user
> - mark -> sub user
> - dave -> sub user
> - dave -> sub user

But this was the unexpected output

> - john -> sub user
> - john -> sub user

**Only the username `john` has appeared**

```
// Get all the users
$s = $sqlConnection->query('SELECT * FROM accounts');

while ($row = $s->fetch_assoc())
{
    $uarr = explode(',', $row['username']);

    foreach ($uarr as $ueach)
    {        
        // Get all the direct sales
        $query = "SELECT *";
        $query .= " FROM accounts ACC";
        $query .= " INNER JOIN info INF ON ACC.user_id = INF.iuid";
        $query .= " INNER JOIN sales SAL ON ACC.user_id = SAL.suid";
        $query .= " WHERE SAL.mentor = '$ueach'";

        $s = $sqlConnection->query($query);

        if (!$s) 
        {
            die($sqlConnection->error);
        }

        while ($row = $s->fetch_assoc())
        {
            echo $ueach . ' -> ' . $row['username'] . '<br/>';
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the database structure

accounts

```
user_id | username |
--------+----------+
 1      | john     |
--------+----------+
 2      | mark     |
--------+----------+
 3      | dave     |
--------+----------+
```

info

```
iuid     |
---------+
1        |
---------+
2        |
---------+
3        |
---------+
```

sales

```
suid    | mentor   |
--------+----------+
 1      | john     |
--------+----------+
 2      | mark     |
--------+----------+
 3      | dave     |
--------+----------+
```

Comment: Are you sure there is a row in `sales` and `info` table for each row of `accounts` table. If not may be you should use `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Not sure why you need two queries here. It seems you could get all of the sub users and their mentors with one query.

Comment: Didnt you just ask this question?

Comment: _It still smells like a very bad database design to me_

Comment: You had better show us what is in `accounts.username`

Comment: @JayBlanchard _RE:One query_ Check the `$uarr = explode(',', $row['username']);` I think that say it all

Comment: Yikes @RiggsFolly - I missed that. What is in `username`? Do both tables have a `username` column? Maybe you should show us the table layout keziah

Comment: I will say this Wonce more **Show us what is in the column `accounts.username`** and then I am off to do something more productive

Comment: Now that you've updated - what is the `explode()` function being used for?

Comment: to put those usernames into list (array)

Comment: You can skip that if you use only one query as shown in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get all of your data with one query, rather than using two. Because of the JOINs the data you need is readily available:

```
SELECT SAL.mentor AS mentor, ACC.username AS username
FROM accounts ACC
LEFT JOIN info INF ON ACC.user_id = INF.iuid
LEFT JOIN sales SAL ON ACC.user_id = SAL.suid
ORDER BY SAL.mentor
```

When you return the rows you will have `$row['mentor']` and `$row['username']` available to you.

```
$query = "SELECT SAL.mentor AS mentor, ACC.username AS username ";
$query .= "FROM accounts ACC ";
$query .= "LEFT JOIN info INF ON ACC.user_id = INF.iuid ";
$query .= "LEFT JOIN sales SAL ON ACC.user_id = SAL.suid ";
$query .= "ORDER BY SAL.mentor ";

$s = $sqlConnection->query($query);

if (!$s) 
{
     die($sqlConnection->error);
} 
else 
{
    while ($row = $s->fetch_assoc())
   {
        echo $row['mentor'] . ' -> ' . $row['username'] . '<br/>';
   }

}
```

Comment: I want this too because later on I'll save it into the database like what i have mentioned above (updated post)

Comment: @keziah this answers your original question better than mine. your updates provide what seems like a [follow-up question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19457/where-should-i-post-follow-up-questions), try sticking to [one question per question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308796/is-there-a-way-of-grouping-a-bunch-of-related-question-you-want-to-ask-so-that-a#308834) because the [help center says](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) that we should *"avoid trying to answer questions which...request answers to multiple questions."* if you still need help, post anew

Answer (score 2):

You're reassigning the result set overwriting `$s`

Choose a different variable for your inner loop query

```
$second = $sqlConnection->query($query);
```

Comment: _Shucks_ Totally missed that

Comment: Good eye Jeff - I missed that too. Of course if her database were formed correctly she would only need one query and would not have run into the problem.

Comment: please look again to my post cuz I've added something which is hard to move on. please let me know about it and what could be the problem behind it.